# Access dynamically generated button

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery and datatables to generate edit and delete buttons dynamically. I need to access them later with javascript and I can't make it work.

I have this render function:

```
render: function (data) {
                            var actions = '';
                            actions += '<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">';
                            actions += '<div id="'+data.id+'" class="buttonUpdate btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></div>';
                            actions += '<div id="'+data.id+'" class="buttonDelete btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></div>';
                            actions += '</div>';
                            return actions;
                        }
```

And I can see the buttons showing correctly.

I try to get an event with:

```
    $('.buttonDelete').click( function () {
        alert('button clicked');
        console.log(this.id);
        //window.location.href = "{!! route('employee') !!}/"+employee_id;
    } );
```

But it is not doing anything :(.

How can i get the event and also how can I see if the button is generated correctly with the right id and class?

Comment: Check out [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). Your handler doesn't work because it's explicitly assigned to elements that existed before the handler was initialized. Dynamically added elements must have their propagated events handled on a parent element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [Delegated Events](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

Change:

```
$('.buttonDelete').click( function () {
```

to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttonDelete', function () {
```

Comment: Feel free to copy-pasta the explanation and link from my comment, if you want.